# Installing and start using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, bash, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have just recently installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using `pip install virtualenv` and `pip install virtualenvwrapper`. I already had Python 2.7 installed on my computer, and I also installed Python 3.5. As far as I can see, both `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper.sh` were stored in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin`.

I am quite new to virtualenvs and would like an explanation as to how the virtual environments are connected to different versions of Python. What I mean by this is:

1. Does it matter where the `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper.sh` files were stored?
2. From the installation guides I see that the `~/.home_profile` is updated by setting `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, but my `virtualenvwrapper.sh` file is stored specifically in the path mentioned above. Do I just have to change `/usr/local/bin` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin` in order to get the same result?
3. When working in a specific virtual environment, how can I most easily make sure that I use the intended version of Python?

Comment: For Q3: by working in a specific virtual environment. That's the whole point; `python` then refers to whichever interpreter you specified when creating the environment. For Q1 and Q2; are you sure they're not in `bin` too? What does `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep virtual` show? Did you *try* `source`-ing the script where you found it?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe 

Both of does files are in the /bin directory of the path from Library/Frameworks/... but in the installing guide, the standard seems to be usr/local/bin .

And that command you posted shows nothing,  its a valid command but no output.
And I have tried to source the script where I found it by altering the /usr/local/bin path to /Library/Frameworks/.../bin.

Comment: And what happened when you reloaded the terminal after doing so?

Comment: Just a valid command, no response message.

Comment: But now when I try to create a virtualenv I get the following response message:

My-MacBook-Pro: $HOME$ mkvirtualenv test_proj
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5'

Comment: New python executable in /Users/MyName/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /Users/MyName/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper

So it seems to have been created, but not quite successfully?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've ended up where you are, and it's not practical to debug comment by comment. I suggest following a guide to getting a Python dev environment set up on OS X, see e.g. https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref

Comment: Thanks for all your help!